# Properties of Fourier transform of a function on a finite group

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$ and $a: G \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ is a function. How do we prove that the following two statements are equivalent?

(1) $\widehat{a}(\chi)$ is real for all $\chi\in \widehat{G}$;

(2) $a(g)=a(g^{-1})$ for all $g\in G$.

Here $\widehat{G}$ is the set of all non-equivalent irreducible characters of $G$, and $\widehat{a}$ is the Fourier transformation defined as
$$\widehat{a}(\chi)=\sum\limits_{g\in G}a(g)\overline{\chi(g)}$$.

I am trying to use the Fourier inversion formula and get the result:

We have
\begin{align*}
a(g^{-1})&=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{\chi\in\widehat{G}}\widehat{a}(\chi)\chi(g^{-1})\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{\chi\in\widehat{G}}\widehat{a}(\chi)\overline{\chi}(g).
\end{align*}
Now if $(1)$ implies $\widehat{a}(\chi)=\widehat{a}(\overline{\chi})$, then we will be done. But I am not able to prove that as well!

For example assuming $(1)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\widehat{a}(\chi)&=\overline{\widehat{a}(\chi)}\\
&=\overline{\sum\limits_{g\in G}a(g)\overline{\chi(g)}}\\
&=\sum\limits_{g\in G}\overline{a}(g)\overline{\overline{\chi}(g)}\\
&=\widehat{\overline{a}}(\overline{\chi}).
\end{align*}

I am not getting any other idea to prove this result. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a mistake in $(2)$.  It should be $a(g)=\overline{a(g^{-1})}$.

Comment: Thank you. I could solve it now. Actually, this was in an exercise of a book, so thought it to be correct.